# Questions and answers not appearing in the Low Quality queue?

Tags: support, bug, review, low-quality-posts

I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148020/334849) (now since deleted, and 10k-only) on SO that had a number of canned comments which indicated to me that it had entered the Low Quality review queue.

Noticing the answer was still around, I went to the Low Quality queue to cast my delete vote to clean it up.  However, when I went to the review queue, it showed 0 items to be reviewed.  When I clicked on the "Low Quality Posts" link, I got the message:

> There are no items for you to review.

However, when I went to the History tab, I saw the answer in the history.  I then saw Bohemian's vote for the question, and clicked on the "Delete" link next to it, and I was taken to [the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1970165#./1970165?&_suid=136663866985205254160221593861) where I could then cast my vote.

**The question**:  if this was a valid item for review, how come it wasn't showing up in the review queue?  I *had* flagged it as Not An Answer; could that cause it to be excluded from my review queue list?

**Update:**   It happened again with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1970737#./1970737?&_suid=13666432684820654693623415286), which I hadn't flagged, so it's reproducable and not related to flagging.

I haven't naturally seen a LQ question in the queue in weeks; I've had to look at the history tab and vote from there.

Comment: My guess is that someone already "reserved their slot". So to keep 50 people from overrunning the same post, it only appears to the first N people who click on it. Then they have X amount of time to review it before they give up their opportunity.

Comment: My first instinct is caching.

Comment: @Sklivvz - so this isn't a bug?  Can you please explain what it is?